# Custom client-side validation in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a simple custom validation. It works ok on server side (with `ModelState.IsValid`), but I would like to make it run on client side.

Regular validators such as `Required` and `RegularExpression` are working great on client side.

My custom attribute:

```cs
public class UniqueSkuAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object? value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false; 
        }

        // IsValueExist() is my own method
        return IsValueExist(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

My property:

```cs
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Value is needed")]
[UniqueSku(ErrorMessage = "Value already exist")]
[RegularExpression("^\\d{11}[a-zA-Z]{2}$", ErrorMessage = "Value in template of: 01234567890xx")]
public string SKU { get; set; }
```

The view that use that property:

```html
<div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
    <input asp-for="SKU" maxlength="13" class="form-control" placeholder="SKU">
    <label asp-for="SKU">Project SKU</label>
    <span asp-validation-for="SKU" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Additionally, I added of course the `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml` file as partial to each view page.

There is a reason why custom validator is not working on client side?

Comment: so.. thing is, the c# code lives on the server while client side validation lives on the client. you got to cook your own validator javascript if its custom. the .net can't translate what you wrote in c# into javascript.

Comment: Could you please guide me to where I can learn to to such thing?

Answer (score 2):

The logic of `IsValueExist` needs to be replicated on the client side and added to the unobtrusive validation library for this to work, something like this:

C#

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class UniqueSkuAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
        var errorMsg = FormatErrorMessage(context.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName());
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-uniquesku", errorMsg);
    }
    public override bool IsValid(object? value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // IsValueExist() is my own method
        return IsValueExist(value.ToString());
    }

    private bool MergeAttribute(
                IDictionary<string, string> attributes,
                string key,
                string value)
    {
        if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return false;
        }
        attributes.Add(key, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

JS

```
$.validator.addMethod("uniquesku",
    function (value, element, parameters) {
        // Here goes your IsValueExist logic that returns bool
    });

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("uniquesku", [], function (options) {
    options.rules.uniquesku = {};
    options.messages["uniquesku"] = options.message;
});
```

Comment: Where should I put the `js` code?
I tried in the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`, `jquery-validate/additional-methods.js` and  `jquery-validation/additional-methods.js.

Comment: @YaronBinder In a separate js script on the page where the control is. and make sure the unobtrusive validation library is loaded as well.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to implement this in your client side.

For example, lets say you have a model like below :

```
public class TestClass
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress] // You can even pass your own regex's here
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

you can refer it in you client side template like below :

```
<input class="form-control" asp-for="Input.Name">
      <label asp-for="Input.Name"></label>
      <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" asp-validation-for="Input.Name"></span>
<input class="form-control" asp-for="Input.Email">
      <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
      <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" asp-validation-for="Input.Email"></span>
```

Look for the attribute `asp-validation-for` attribute in the template which does the magic on the client side for pairing up the validation in your model class into the template.

As a reference please refer the link [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AG9F1p).

Comment: In order to learn more  refer https://andrewlock.net/adding-client-side-validation-to-aspnet-core-without-jquery-or-unobtrusive-validation/